# Listview read all data when outside button click?

Tags: android

This is my code for read data from listview but its read only data which are seen in display but not read below data.

here below attachment of code.it execute 8 times on my display seen 8 records.
there is 20 records in my listview.

How to read all data.?

```
for(int i = 0; i< listEditTest.getAdapter().getCount();i++){

            View convertView = listEditTest.getChildAt(i);

            TextView TestName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_test_edit_name);
            TextView TestValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_result_edit_val);
            EditText TestEditValue = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_result_edit_para_val);
            TextView TestAppId  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_test_AppId);
            TextView TestAppTestId  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_test_AppTestId);
            TextView TestResultId  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_test_AppTestResultId);
            TextView TestProfileName  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_test_ProfileName);
            TextView TestParameter  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_test_testParameterName);
            TextView TestParaDesc  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_test_testParaDesc);
            Log.d("value",TestEditValue.getText().toString());


            String stTName = TestName.getText().toString();
            String stTValue = TestValue.getText().toString();
            String stTEditValue = TestEditValue.getText().toString();
            String stAppIds = TestAppId.getText().toString();
            String stAppTestId = TestAppTestId.getText().toString();
            String stResultId = TestResultId.getText().toString();
            String stProfileName = TestProfileName.getText().toString();
            String stPara = TestParameter.getText().toString();
            String stParaDesc = TestParaDesc.getText().toString();

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.accumulate("AppointmentID", stAppIds);
                jsonObject.accumulate("AppointmentTestID", stAppTestId);
                jsonObject.accumulate("TestResultID", stResultId);
                jsonObject.accumulate("TestProfileName", stProfileName);
                jsonObject.accumulate("TestName", stPara);
                jsonObject.accumulate("TestParameter", stTName);
                jsonObject.accumulate("TestParameterDescription", stParaDesc);
                jsonObject.accumulate("TestParameterValue", stTValue);
                jsonObject.accumulate("TestParameterUpdatedValue", stTEditValue);
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(EditPatientTest.this, "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Well, that's how List Adapter is suppose to behave, i.e. Only visible elements should be read. Just imagine when you want it to read all data and your list have, say millions of records.

Comment: Create a method in your adapter and return all the data.

Comment: which method create in adapter?
If possible then send me a example.
thank you..